# Using babel-polyfill in production entry file

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-2017, babel-polyfill, babel-cli, babel-core

I'm using babel to transpile ES7 js code, and everything works like a charm in dev/staging. Inside the application, I heavily rely on *async/await* features of ES7. My entry file looks like this:

```
'use strict';
require("babel-polyfill");
require("babel-core/register");
module.exports = require('./app/server').default();
```

I'm not sure whether it is necessary to keep *babel-polyfill* and *babel-core/register* modules for the production environment since I transpile everything using babel-cli before deployment. I assume it must correctly work even if I remove those and make the entry file look something like this:

```
import server from './app/server';
server();
```

However, if do this I got next exception while starting the application:

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at C:\Users\Username\Documents\some-service\lib\app\repositories\someRepository.js:18:32
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Username\Documents\some-service\lib\app\repositories\someRepository.js:40:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Username\Documents\some-service\lib\app\controllers\someController.js:15:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Username\Documents\some-service\lib\app\server.js:15:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

Is that normal to reference *babel-polyfill* and *babel-core/register* packages in the production environment?

Comment: The polyfill is always required.

Comment: @Bergi, that what I'm thinking about. All I want is some link to documentation which says this. This might be obvious for someone, but I haven't found any mentions about using production environment

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7 (ES2016). It will be part of this year's release (ES2017).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are relying on those modules (babel-polyfill and babel-core/register) during development, you will also need them in your production file. The transpilation process does not add polyfills like `Object.assign` or `Promise`.

The [docs page for the babel polyfills](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) does not explicitly say that you should include different libraries for dev and production. But it *does* say you will need to include it or specific polyfills for the features you want, which seems to say you need them in *any* environment.

Short answer: It is standard to include polyfills in every environment, since transpilation by babel does not add polyfills on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will mark as an answer since no one seems to have any objections